# C++ c2334 error message

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
// Assignment-Cat 1.cpp : Defines the entry podouble for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

class Rectangle
{
public : 
    void set_values (double a, double b);

protected : 
   double width, height;
   {
       width = a; height = b;
   }

};

class Triangle: public Rectangle
{
public : 
    double area()
    {
        return (width*height*0.5);
    }
};


int main()
{
    Triangle tri;
    tri.set_values (4,5);
    cout<<tri.area()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is **c2334 unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body**Someone please help debug
`

Comment: If you format your code better and read what's the error description, you'll find errors easier.

Comment: For reference, it's always best to post the line number that the error message refers to, and point it out in a concise code example (not a complete program)

Comment: Also, I don't think triangle should inherit from a rectangle.  A triangle is not a rectangle.  It might have a rectangle member though, since it can have rectangle members.

Answer (score 4):

You messed the class definition, You intended to define a inline function but you mixed it with member declarations.

```
class Rectangle
{
public : void set_values (double a, double b);

protected : double width, height;
    {
        width = a; height = b;
        }

};
```

Should actually be:

```
class Rectangle
{
public : 
   void set_values (double a, double b)
   {
        width = a; height = b;
   }

protected : 
   double width, height;

};
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got a function body:

```
{
  width = a; height = b;
}
```

with no function declaration. I think you probably wanted this body under the set_values() declaration

Comment: Please give me a sample of what u want me to change

Comment: "of what u want me to change" - you've got to be kidding me..

Comment: @als did it for you 4 inches down from this message.

Answer (score 1):

just mess with the brackets

```
class Rectangle
{
protected : double width, height;

public : void set_values (double a, double b)
            {
                width = a; height = b;
            }

};

class Triangle: public Rectangle
{
public : double area()
         {
             return (width*height*0.5);
         }
};


int main()
{
    Triangle tri;
    tri.set_values (4,5);
    cout<<tri.area()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ps: try to use some common c++ code formating like:

```
class Rectangle
{
protected:
    double width, height;

public:
    void set_values (double a, double b)
    {
        width = a; height = b;
    }

};

class Triangle: public Rectangle
{
public:
    double area()
    {
        return (width*height*0.5);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a good C++ book.  You appear to be attempting to write a function for `Rectangle`, but the syntax is all wrong:

```
class Rectangle
{
public : 
    void set_values (double a, double b)
    {
        width = a; height = b;
    }
protected : 
    double width, height;
};
```